# Azure Mobile server update script w/ complex field type

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've got a complex data type "AzureTemplate" containing a list of children "AzureField". I've implemented my read and insert on the server side according to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/08/23/complex-types-and-azure-mobile-services.aspx). Works great.

Needing an update as well, I copy/pasted the insert into the update so it does the same thing, but using update instead. So my update looks like this:

```
function update(item, user, request) {     
// remove complex child object, make copy first
var fields = item.fields;
if (fields) {
    delete item.fields;
}
request.execute({
    success: function () {  
        var templateId = item.id; // "foreign key" 
        var fieldsTable = tables.getTable('AzureFields');
        if (fields) {
            // update the child fields
            var updateNextField = function (index) {
                if (index >= fields.length) {
                    // done updating fields, respond to client
                    request.respond();
                } else {
                    var field = fields[index];
                    field.templateId = templateId;

                    // *** THE ID LOGGED HERE LOOKS FINE ***
                    console.log("updating field w/ id ", field.id);
                    fieldsTable.update(field, {
                        success: function () {
                            updateNextField(index + 1);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            // kick off the loop saving each field
            updateNextField(0);

        } else {
            // no fields. no need to do anything else
            request.respond();
        }
    }
});
}
```

The log that prints the ID of the child "field" shows a valid field id (I save them on the client side when reading them). But I get an error that says:

```
Error in script '/table/AzureTemplate.update.js'. Error: Invalid id value specified.    AzureTemplate/update    Tue Jan 27 2015, 10:11:31 AM
```

I put a console.log() at the top of the AzureField.update, but that never shows up, so it's not getting in there. Also, when I update a single child "Field" directly from the client it works fine. So the AzureField.update is working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fieldsTable = tables.getTable('AzureFields');
```

... my table name is **AzureField**, not **AzureFields**. The above code works, hopefully it helps someone.

I have misnamed a table before and got a meaningful error about "table not existing". Not sure why the error in this case is totally unrelated.